# Why do the following C expressions involving pointers not evaluate to an error?

Tags: c, pointers

I have been reviewing material regarding C for the upcoming semester, and stumbled across some topics involving pointers and memory. I did not write the code, but I am trying to understand all of it. The expressions are as follows (for conciseness I removed int main()):

```
int x = 5;
int y;
int *p = NULL;
p = &x;

y = *p + 2; /* y is assigned 7 */
y += *p;     /* y is assigned 12 */
*p = y;       /* x is assigned 12 */
(*p)++;      /* x is incremented to 13 */
```

I do not understand the 7th statement, because it isn't consistent with the way the 5th statement is evaluated. As far as I was concerned, *p is used to access the value p points to, being x, which is 5. In the 5th statement, we set y = *p + 2, which evaluates to y = 5 + 2 = 7. So, why in the 7th statement is *p used as a pointer to x, and not the value 5? (ie. why doesn't the expression evaluate to 5 = 12 and give an error?).

Thanks for any of the help, appreciate it.

Comment: Replace all instances of `*p` with `x`, not `5`.  IOW, `y = *p + 2` is equivalent to `y = x + 2`, and `*p = y` is equivalent to `x = y`.

Comment: For the same reason `x=y;` is valid. `*p=y` is telling - assign the value of `y` to that variable/memory location `p` is pointing to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`*p = y;` sets `*p` to the value of `y` and does not set 5 to the value of `y` for the same reason that `x = y;` sets `x` to the value of `y` and does not set 5 to the value of `y`.

Specifically, in most places, when there is expression that refers to an object, like `x` or `*p` or `y`, it is automatically converted to the value stored in that object. This is why, in `x = y;`, the `y` is converted to 12. This conversion occurs due to C 2018 6.3.2.1, which says:

> … an lvalue that does not have array type is converted to the value stored in the designated object (and is no longer an lvalue)…

But the full sentence lists exceptions:

> Except when it is the operand of the `sizeof` operator, the unary `&` operator, the `++` operator, the `--` operator, or the left operand of the `.` operator or an assignment operator, an lvalue that does not have array type is converted to the value stored in the designated object (and is no longer an lvalue)…

In `x = y;` or `*p = y;`, the `x` or `*p` is the left operand of an assignment operator. So these are not converted to values. Each remains an *lvalue*. An lvalue is a reference to an object; it designates the object itself, not its value.

So `x = y;` puts the value of `y` into the object referred to by `x`, and `*p = y;` puts the value of `y` into the object referred to by `*p`.

Answer (score 0):

> why doesn't the expression evaluate to 5 = 12

It's possible to *write* to the memory pointed to by a pointer.

Similarly, `x = y;` is valid because you can *read* from the variable `y` and you can *write* to `x`. Same thing with pointers: `*p = *p + 1;`, for example, will read from `p`, add one to that value and *write* the result back to `p`.